# == operator in assign statement (Verilog)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, ternary-operator, assign, hdl

I am trying to understand some of the System Verilog syntax. I was struggling to finish an assignment and I came across this solution, but I do not understand why it works.

```
localparam int lo = w;
uwire [n:0] lo_bits, hi_bits;
assign answer = lo_bits == nlo ? lo_bits + hi_bits : lo_bits;
```

This is not exactly what I have in my code, but my question is the following: Why can't I rewrite this to a simple if-else block as such?

```
if (lo == lo_bits)
    assign answer = lo_bits + hi_bits;
else
    assign answer = lo_bits;
```

Verilog complains that lo_bits is a uwire and I cannot compare it with lo, but then why is it allowed in the example above? Aren't these two assignments equivalent?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is structural/declarative context versus procedural context. When you use an `if` clause in a declarative context (in this case it is at the same top level where you declare your wires and variables), it is considered a *conditional generate construct* (See Section 27.5 in the 1800-2017 LRM). This means the *condition* gets evaluated before simulation starts and must contain only constant expressions and no signals that can change during simulation. `lo` is a constant parameter, but not `lo_bits`.

If you want to use a procedural `if`, it needs to be inside a procedural block of code instantiated by always/initial blocks.

```
logic [n:0] answer;
always_comb
  if (lo == lo_bits)
    answer = lo_bits + hi_bits;
else
    answer = lo_bits;
```